# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exception : 0 at runtime

Tags: java

I have the error `ArrayIndexOutofBounds`. Please help me I am newbie to java.

```
class Sum{
   int a,b,c;
   void assign (int x, int y){
      a=x;
      b=y;
   }
   void add(){
     c=a+b;
   }
   void disp(){
     System.out.println("Sum of"+a+"and"+b+"is ="+c);
   }
}
class SumDemo{
   public static void main(String k[]){
      int x=Integer.parseInt (k [0]);
      int y=Integer.parseInt (k [1]);
      Sum s0=new Sum();
      s0.assign(x,y);
      s0.add();
      s0.disp();
   }
}
```

this is the code. please help me . why this error is occurring?

Comment: Probably you does not pass any parameter values.

Comment: You should start using indentation to make your code easy to read. Also can we see how are you running this code?

Comment: It suggests that `k` is empty (i.e. doesn't have an element at index 0).

Comment: what can I do to resolve the error?

Comment: changed the values of K[0] and k[1] to k[1] and k[2] .... but same error occurs.

Comment: @user2804097 Figure out why `k` is empty when you're expecting it not to be. Your array `k` **has no elements**, any index you try to access will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error.

Comment: now the ArrayIndexOutof Bounds : 1......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why this error is occurring?

The error is occurring because you are attempting to access element zero of an array that doesn't have an element zero.  The javadoc for [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) explains this.  The message gives the actual index that that your code attempted to use.  (The javadocs don't say what the message contains, but that is the observed behaviour for all JVM's I recall.)

So it must be this line:

```
    int x=Integer.parseInt (k [0]);
```

Your code should test the length of the `k` array (`k.length`) to make sure that there are (at least) 2 command line arguments.

---

You write:

> ... the mistake is that I am not passing Run Time Values.....

That is one diagnosis.  The other is that your program *does not check* that it has been called with the right number of command line parameters.  (Both diagnoses are correct ... in their own ways.)

Comment: Thankss alot everyone.....I got the answer......the mistake is that I am not passing Run Time Values........such a noob.

Answer (score 0):

When you run it, you aren't passing the required command line arguments for k[0] and k[1].

```
if (k.length < 2) {
  System.err.println("Missing arguments x and y, exiting.");
  System.exit(1);
}
int x=Integer.parseInt (k [0]);
int y=Integer.parseInt (k [1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines are problematic if you are not passing any program arguments:

```
int x=Integer.parseInt (k [0]);
int y=Integer.parseInt (k [1]);
```

If you are running from command prompt then use:

```
java SumDemo 1 2
```

If you are using Eclipse IDE you can set these arguments using `Run Configurations`

Answer (score 0):

Only reason can be that you are not entering the arguments while running the program.

run as java SubDemo 2 3